# How to write the ok button action in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am new in [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode). I have created a dialog and ok button on the dialog. Now, I am doing some operation on dialog. After that I want to click on ok button to close the dialog box. for this I am doing like

**in .h file**

```
@interface viewcontroller:NSViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *OkBtn;

@end
```

**in .m file**

"I don't know how to write the code for ok button in .m file. I just want to when click on OK button , just close the dialog.

Comment: Couldn't you just use an UIAlert?

Answer (score 12):

Instead of create IBOutlet, you have to make `IBAction` to directly get click event

check out this image...
[image]

This Is `.m` file where i create `IBAction` directly

and if you want to give click event programatically then follow @Nicolas Buquet answer

Comment: +1 for the animation, however there are a few problems: 1) You should've shown the Ctrl+dragging and 2) I don't like the way you named the method (more precisely the fact that you're indirectly influencing others(beginners) on how to name them). Methods should be actions. Looking at `btnOk`, I expect it to be the property itself. The method for it should be named something like `btnOkTapped:`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:

```
[OkBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(okButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and add this method to your class:

```
- (void)okButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
NSLog(@"Ok button was tapped: dismiss the view controller.");
}
```

The `okButtonTapped:` method will be called when you tap iside the button and remove your finger (the 'up" part).

Comment: While correct, I would rarely suggest doing it like this on an `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Create`IBAction` for`NSButton`. And connect `IBAction` to the button.

in interface file (.h) file write,

```
- (IBAction) okButtonAction : (id) sender;
```

and in your implementation file (.m)

```
- (IBAction) okButtonAction : (id) sender {
   NSLog(@"OK Button action here");
}
```